# Multiple kylefox jquery modal boxes

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have multiple elements that contain modal boxes, and for some reason the boxes will open on first click only.

```
$(function(){
    $('a[data-modal').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('div').modal();
        return false;
    });
});

<article>
    <div>Modal One <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC </div>
    <a href="#" data-modal>Open Modal</a>
</article>
<article>
    <div>Modal Two <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC </div>
    <a href="#" data-modal>Open Modal</a>
</article>
```

Thanks!

Js Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/td9vfctz/2/

Comment: updated my answer. Have a look please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/td9vfctz/3/)

Commented out this part:

```
//this.$body.append(this.$elm);
```

It was removing target element from it's place and putting it into body. That's why `$(this).parent().find('div')` couldn't be found, if you launch modal second time.

**Edit**

You can also do it this way, by appending clone of the element to the body:

```
this.$body.append(this.$elm.clone().hide());
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/td9vfctz/4/)

**Edit 2**

If you don't want to change the plugin itself here is the solution:

```
 $('a[data-modal').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('div').clone().modal();
      return false;
 });
```

[**DEMO 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/td9vfctz/5/)

Comment: Thanks Said :) Is there a way to do this without editing the core plugin?

Comment: Try to clone it when as you call modal() function @Rich on click